# How can I pass a variable as a string into a function in bash?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have a small bash script that does simple file modifications and I want to rewrite the code to be more readable. My goal is to pass Commands as strings into a function that loops the command over a Directory.

I've tried to use different methods to escape the "$" or different """ combinations but none really work.

```
#!/bin/bash
process="/Users/Gernot/Tools/.Process"
output="/Users/Gernot/Tools/2 Output"
input="/Users/Gernot/Tools/1 Input/"

function run {

    for file in "$input$1"/*
    do
        echo "running procedure $1" #echoes which procedure is running
        $2 #does the command for every file in the directory

    done


}



run "PDF Komprimieren" "magick convert \$file -density 110 -compress jpeg -quality 100 \$file"
```

This is the error I get:

```
running procedure PDF Komprimieren
convert: unable to open image '$file': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3497.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/556.
convert: no images defined `$file' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273.
```

Comment: you can use `eval`, eg. `$(eval echo "$input/$1)`.  It looks like you want to loop through your args as well

Comment: Don't pass commands as strings but make different functions like `pdf_komprimieren()` and `magick_convert()` which will be, IMHO, more readable. Even when you get your command evaluated, the spaces in the dirname and perhaps filename will cause more problems.

Comment: First, I would like to point out that it is a bad practice. The simple hack would be using the evil `eval` before `$2`.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi No I don't want to loop through my args. I'll try your tip thanks

Comment: ah ok, didnt look taht closely

Comment: @WalterA Yeah could try that. I want to try to make it very compact tho. Still learning so I'm also experimenting a bit here.

Comment: Storing commands as strings is hard to get right in complex cases; see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @anishsane I put a eval before the $2 but I get another error:" convert:  `100' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3270."

Do you know what this error is about ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using functions like

```
pdf_komprimieren() {
   find "PDF Komprimieren" -maxdepth 2 -type f -print0 |
     xargs --null -n1 -Ifile magick convert "file" -density 110 -compress jpeg -quality 100 "file"
}
```